# Order by multiple columns in SQL

Tags: oracle

Hello I would like to order by multiple columns.

1. Sort Descending Plan leg
2. Sort Ascending No of days
3. Sort Descending Time

I understand the following SQL code can be used. However this does not work for some reason in the specific ETL online tool I am using.

```
SELECT
       plane_check AS plane_leg,
       min(trunc(ead_date)- trunc(pickup_date_ts)) AS no_of_days,
       to_char(max(pickup_date_ts),'HH24:MI') as time

from
       final_leg
group by
       plane_check, trunc(pickup_date_ts)
order by
plane_leg DESC, no_of_days ASC, time DESC
```

Hence I would like someone to suggest a concatenation or other method to sort this data
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the `Time` column a TIME datatype or a VARCHAR?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is a datetime

Comment: Then that query did not generate that output ??

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is a datetime, however I am using the following to convert it to time to_char(max(time),'HH24:MI')

Comment: So show us the REAL Query you are runing. Pseudo code will get you Pseudo Answers

Comment: Is this MysQL or Oracle? I cant find a `trunc()` func in MySQL

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated the question I am using Oracle

Comment: Try changing `time DESC` to `pickup_date_ts DESC` so you dort on a datetime column and not a Char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    PLANE_LEG,
    NO_OF_DAYS,
    TIME
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            PLANE_LEG,
            NO_OF_DAYS,
            TIME,
            TO_NUMBER((PLANE_LEG * 1000)
              ||((MAX(NO_OF_DAYS) OVER() - NO_OF_DAYS) * 100)
              ||(TO_CHAR(TIME, 'HH24') * 10)) AS ORDER_CLAUSE
        FROM
            DATAA
    )
ORDER BY
    ORDER_CLAUSE DESC
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=23325e610e71b113de7856f7ea1166a6)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The above query that you wrote use to work when I was working with Mysql Server 5.0, some reasons along the lines of later versions..it no longer works.

You could group by the data and then do the sort with the following query. let me know if this works

```
Select * from (SELECT
              plane_check AS plane_leg,
              min(trunc(ead_date)- trunc(pickup_date_ts)) AS no_of_days,
              to_char(max(pickup_date_ts),'HH24:MI') as time
              from
              final_leg
              group by
              plane_check, trunc(pickup_date_ts)) t1
order by
plane_leg DESC, no_of_days ASC, time DESC
```

Comment: I tried this as well, the sorting still deosnt work as well. This is why I was thinking of somehow using a concatanation to sort the data

Comment: I am using Oracle, I updated the tag in the question